# MongoDB's mapReduce: partition keys to single reducers and affect key sorting

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm really stuck at a point, where I have to enforce the **mapReduce** framework to use only one `reducer` for a specific key. Also I want to affect how the framework sorts keys. I'll introduce the problem on an example:

I would like to emit key value pairs in the following form:

> < **b x b** > : < d1 > 
>      < **b x** >   : < d2 > 
>      < **b** >     : < d3 > 
>      < **b a x** > : < d2, d3 > 
>      *figure 1*

The key is a sequence - as you see -, each starts with an item **b**, which would be a data type `string`. Values would be `ObjectID`s as noted with letter **d** and a number. There are other key value pairs I emit from a `map` function, which starts with a different item in their keys, for example **a** or **x**:

> < **a b x** > : < d1 > 
>      < **a x** > : < d3 > 
>      < **x a a** > : < d3 > 
>      *figure 2*

I need to force the framework to call a single `reduce` function for each key-value pairs, which starts with a specific item. Also I have to force a sort between `map` and `reduce` to sort keys in reverse lexicographic order. So a single reducer would receive the following key-value pairs for item **b**:

> < **b x b** > : < d1 > 
>      < **b x** >   : < d2 > 
>      < **b a x** > : < d2, d3 > 
>      < **b** >     : < d3 > 
>      *figure 3*

*What I've tried:*

I've tried to emit key-value pairs in the following form:

> **b** : < (d1 : < **b x b** >) > 
>      **b** : < (d2 : < **b x** >) > 
>      **b** : < (d3 : < **b** >) > 
>      **b** : < (d2 : < **b a x** >), (d3 : < **b a x** >) > 
>      *figure 4*

This way a single reducer received values for the item **b**, but as you see not in a reverse lexicographic order, and the worst part is, that there is no guarantee that a single reducer would get all values for a specific key ([as MongoDB's MapReduce documentation states](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function)).

Basically: **I have to process these sequences that starts with a specific item in reverse lexicographic order.**

I have no ideas that would lead me further to the solution. How can I enforce single reducers for keys and affect sorting? **How should I design the data structure** passed (emitted) to fulfill my needs?

*These functions would be similar to Hadoop's `Comparator` and `Partitioner`.*

**UPDATE ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

It has been pointed out to me by Asya Kamsky, that `finalize` runs only once per key, so it solves the partitioning problem, when every value must seen by a single reducer for a specific key.

The sorting is still a problem. For large datasets, implementing my own sort inside `finalize` would mean a huge bottleneck in terms of execution time, while I'm not utilizing the natural sort mechanism between `map` and `reduce`. The keys are of data type `string`, but it would be easy to encode them as negative `integers` to force reverse sorting.

Let's check *figure 3* again:

> < **b x b** > : < d1 > 
>      < **b x** >   : < d2 > 
>      < **b a x** > : < d2, d3 > 
>      < **b** >     : < d3 > 
>      *figure 3*

This is, what a `finalize` would have to receive for key **b**. The keys, for example `< b x b >` are composite here. Finalize would need to receive keys that start with **b**, but for other parts of the key, in reverse lexicographic order.

Is there any way to achieve this and avoid the sort inside `finalize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is emit documents "normally" and use reduce to combine all emitted values into a sorted array.  Then use `finalize` method to do whatever processing you were going to do in a single reducer.

MongoDB reduce function could be called more than once, but it also could be called never (in case where only a single value is emitted for a particular key).  Using `finalize` would solve both problems as it's called exactly once per key.

Sample data:

```
> db.sorts.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "b" : 1, "a" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 2, "b" : 1, "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "b" : 2, "a" : 12 }
{ "_id" : 4, "b" : 3, "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 5, "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 6, "b" : 3, "a" : 11 }
{ "_id" : 7, "b" : 3, "a" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 8, "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 9, "b" : 1, "a" : 15 }
```

Map function:

```
map = function() {
   emit( this.b, { val: [ this.a ] } );
}
```

Reduce function which adds new incoming val into a sorted array by walking the array:

```
reduce = function( key, values) {
   var result = { val: [ ] };
   values.forEach(function(v) {
      var newval = v.val[0];
      var added = false;
      for (var i=0; i < result.val.length; i++) {
           if (newval < result.val[i]) {
                 result.val.splice(i, 0, newval);
                 added=true;
                 break;
           }
      }
      if ( !added ) {
         result.val.splice(result.val.length, 0, newval);
      }
   });
   return result;
}
```

Finalize just returns a simple array:

```
finalize = function( key, values ) {
   // values is document with a sorted array
   // do your "single reduce" functionality here
   return values.val;
}
```

Run MapReduce:

```
> db.sorts.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:"outs", finalize:finalize})
{
    "result" : "outs",
    "timeMillis" : 10,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 9,
        "emit" : 9,
        "reduce" : 3,
        "output" : 3
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Result is:

```
> db.outs.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : [  2,  15,  20 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : [  1,  1,  12 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : [  1,  5,  11 ] }
```

Comment: This is nice, to start from! I've updated my question to highlight the remaining part of the problem. It would be valuable for me if You'd be able to help me further.

Comment: why don't you take care of sorting in reduce?  rather than straight concat you can add logic which will iterate over values and insert them into the array at an appropriate location.  You have full JS available to you.  And it makes the sorting work "incrementally".  Something like looping over existing array result and when you get to "appropriate" location, use splice function to add a specific element.

Comment: Yeah, that would free up "some (?)" computing juice, but still, a problem exists: For each key, multiple `reduce`s can run. Each `reduce` would be able to sort only the **portion of values** for a specific key in `O(n*log(n))` time. `Finalize` would still receive an array of values, which are unsorted. Sorting an array again in `finalize` for a specific key, which is only sorted in intervals is not faster either.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  You don't need to constantly resort the lists.  You have list of one object to begin with. You add a second object before or after it. Now you have a sorted list of 2.  Third object just needs to be added to appropriate location - in other words you will be adding items one at a time into already sorted lists.  And finalize *will* receive the sorted array that comes out of reduce, I'm not sure where you got the idea that it won't be sorted.

Comment: Hm, I don't see Your idea clearly, I still sense a problem at `finalize`. Could You, please, add an example code for this, updating Your answer?

Comment: I will add example of reduce which sorts and finalize which just outputs what it receives (so you can run it and see that it comes to finalize sorted).  I don't know what processing you need to do for each key in finalize so you would have to fill in what goes there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39529/discussion-between-dyin-and-asya-kamsky)